# New-ADUser -Path syntax?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

Where can I find a detailed explanation of the `-Path` parameter of the `New-ADUser` command?

I want to specify a rather detailed path without calling `Set-Location` many times to specify where I want the user created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [**Technet**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee617253(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> **Path**
> Specifies the X.500 path of the Organizational Unit (OU) or
> container where the new object is created.
> ...
> The following example shows how to set this parameter to an OU.
> `-Path "ou=mfg,dc=noam,dc=corp,dc=contoso,dc=com"`

Answer (score 6):

The technet example posted by squillman is the first place I looked but it doesn't really offer any details on how the path is structured. It basically works like this;

Assuming you're trying to target the nested OU MyCountry>Mystate>Users and your domain is mycompany.int.com your -path parameter would look like this

```
-Path "OU=Users,OU=Mystate,OU=MyCountry,dc=mycompany,dc=int,dc=com"
```

Looking at the above you can pretty much see what going on. You target the nested OU by using multiple comma separated "OU=" starting at the specific OU and working your way backwards up the hierarchy.

The dc is also comprised of several comma separated "dc=" elements. To get this you basically break apart your domain at the periods and put each one into it's own dc element. So mycompany.int.com becomes dc=mycompany,dc=int,dc=com