# The Object name has bad syntax when trying to bulk add AD users using Powershell

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2016, csv

I'm attempting to add a series of User to AD by importing a csv file and I can't seem to get it to run successfully, the error always reads 'the object name has bad syntax' however no matter what kind of error handling I use I don't get any additional information about it.

Here's the script and a snippet from the csv

```
# Import the PowerShell module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Store the data from your CSV file in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-Csv C:\NWTC-users.csv

# Read each row of input data and assign each user’s details to variables
foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
$Firstname = $User.Firstname
$Lastname = $User.Lastname
$Username = $User.LOGINNAME
$OU = $User.OU
$Password = $User.Password

# Attempt to create the new user account in the specified OU
try {
    New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Username `
               -UserPrincipalName "$Username@NWTC.local" `
               -Name "$Firstname $Lastname" `
               -GivenName $Firstname `
               -Surname $Lastname `
               -DisplayName "$Lastname, $Firstname" `
               -Enabled $True `
               -Path $OU `
               -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `
               -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False  # Disable password change at next logon
    
    Write-Host "User account for $Username created successfully."

    # Create home directory
    $HomeDirectory = "\\DC\Home\$Username"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $HomeDirectory | Out-Null

    # Set permissions on home directory
    $ACL = Get-Acl $HomeDirectory
    $Permission = "SYSTEM","FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow"
    $Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Permission)
    $ACL.SetAccessRule($Rule)
    Set-Acl $HomeDirectory $ACL
    
    Write-Host "Home directory for $Username created successfully."
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Failed to create user account for $Username. $_"
}
```

}

```
USERNAME,FirstName,LastName,LOGINNAME,OU,Password
RogerMcGregor,Roger,McGregor,RMCGREGOR,Business,Password1
GaleChen,Gale,Chen,GCHEN,Business,Password1
```

Comment: You need to log the values of each parameters for New-ADUser to identify the offending line. My guess would be broken csv data

Comment: Have you tried running the command individually with the filled in data to see what it doesn’t like? Try changing UserPrincipalName to `”$($Username)@NWTC.local”`. Also I’m pretty sure your path is expected to be in a different format. You can’t just provide the singular name of an OU. It’s expecting an x500 formatted path as documented and demonstrated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps it should be something like `OU=Business,DC=nwtc,DC=local`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/581383/new-aduser-path-syntax